# How to club the rails query along with maximum date condition inside the query

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Application using  ruby 2.4.0p0 Rails 5.2.4.4

I have a software users table now I want to find out the record matching with the username and password along with the maximum valid_upto value which is in datetime.

```
 SoftwareUser.where("user_name = ?  and password = BINARY ? and max(valid_upto) ", user_name, password)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two queries like this.

```
# This is just for convenience so you don't have to type it again for both queries
software_users = SoftwareUser
                  .where(user_name: user_name)
                  .where("password = BINARY ?", password)

# This one gets the max date
max_date = software_users.max(:valid_upto)


# This gets the first record matching that criteria
user_record = software_users.find_by(valid_upto: max_date)
```

---

*However just ordering by `valid_upto` should do the trick unless I'm missing something.*

```
software_users.order(valid_upto: :desc).first
```